# Can JPA cache query every time we execute SELECT statement?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

For example, I have the following query(The implementation of JPA is Hibernate):

```
return em.createQuery("select m.username from Member m", String.class)
        .getResultList();
```

I know JPA will interpret this query into SQL the first time I execute it, but what if the second time? Will JPA interpret it again? This is a time consuming.

If I change all these queries into `NamedQuery`, will there be noticeable performance improvement?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3578933/926620

Comment: @AntonBessonov Yeah I've seen this post. But the answers are somewhat contradictory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the query plan is cached.

This is the flow:

1. `em.createQuery(..)`
2. `org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(String queryString)`
3. `org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(String queryString)`
4. `org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getQueryPlanCache().getHQLQueryPlan( query, .. )`;

So the query is cached in the session factory, so once the query is translated, it is going to be shared among all future sessions.